# Inkscape can't find the file for includesvg

Tags: latex, inkscape, miktex

Having a nightmare including an svg file in my document.  It's just a picture of Tux.

Code:

```
\svgpath{{C:/Users/me/Google\ Drive/foo}}
\includesvg[width = 200pt]{tux}
```

Error:

```
** (inkscape.exe:27228): WARNING **: 20:52:43.840: Can't open file: tux.svg (doesn't exist)

** (inkscape.exe:27228): WARNING **: 20:52:43.840: Can't open file: tux.svg (doesn't exist)

** (inkscape.exe:27228): WARNING **: 20:52:43.840: Specified document tux.svg cannot be opened (does not exist or not a valid SVG file)
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I wish it would give me more debugging information so I could tell what directory is being used. I've enabled `--shell-escape`.  I've tried various combinations with no success.

**EDIT: Minimal example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\begin{document}

  \includesvg{tux}

\end{document}
```

I created a directory `c:\latex`

My command line is `texify --pdf --engine=luatex --synctex=1 --tex-option=--shell-escape --clean foo`

I noticed that it also says there's a log file, but I cannot find a log file with more information

```
Package svg Warning: The export with Inkscape failed for file
(svg)                `tux.svg'
(svg)                Troubleshooting: Please check in the log file how
(svg)                the invocation of Inkscape took place and try to
(svg)                execute it yourself in the terminal on input line 5.
```

I would love to get my hands on that mythical log file.  There's a `foo.log` file but that just says what my console output was.  There's another log file at `C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\texify.log`, but that doesn't have any information about the `inkscape` command either.

The docs (http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/graphics/svg/doc/svg.pdf) say that I should see `runsystem ...`.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @Robert good advice.  I have done that.

Comment: Don't use texify if you can help it. The only thing it is really good at is to hide helpful information from error messages and warnings. For most documents, simply using `pdflatex` should be enough. For more complex documents with bibliographies etc, an automation tool such as latexmk, ltx2any or arara can be handy.

Comment: @samcarter Hmm.  Good point.  I have at least one package that requires LuaLaTeX.  The TexWorks option for `LuaLaTeX +Makeindex +BibTex` seems to be the one using `texify`.  It turns out that I just need the regular `LuaLaTeX` typesetting option.  Thank you for that keen observation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `--clean` option.  I figured this out by selected pdflatex in TeXWorks and it suddenly built.  Taking out options one by one helped me get to the bottom of this.  Going back to post on some other questions.

As @samcarter pointed out, if you don't have to use texify, try not to.  One of my packages requires LuaLaTex to typeset, so I selected the `LuaLaTeX +MakeIndex +BibTex` when I only needed the `LuaLaTex` plain option.  Using that one fixed the issue.

If you have to use texify, though, try removing the `--clean`.

Comment: With inkscapelatex=false even LuaLaTeX fails with the --clean option.  It works without the --clean option.

Answer (score 1):

The question is some years old, but as it is not solved yet, I add my experience here.

You may check if inkscape is properly installed and if the bin-folder of the installation was added to the path-variable. If not, you need to append it to the path-variable and after a restart of your IDE or command prompt everything should work.